# where clause with Arraylist in linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

i have arraylist in which i store string dynamically.

exm:

```
Arraylist a = new Arraylist();
string[] Url = {"ram" ,"syam" }
foreach (var s in Url)
{
a.Insert(0,s);
var person = (from p in db.person
             where a.contain(p.name)
             select p).tolist(); 
}
```

this is my query.but problem is that query filter only works for first item added in arraylist. if first add "syam" and second add "ram" then only fetch "syam" record from the database.i wanna fetch both record from the database . so i have to do ..?

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using an ArrayList instead of a type-safe [Generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)?

Comment: can you tell me how do i use Generic list in my problem ..??

Comment: I added a link in my initial comment to the MSDN reference on lists. It works very similar to an ArrayList, but you get the benefit of type-safety. A simple example of using a list that holds string: `List<string> a = new List<string>();` `a.Add("foo");` `a.Add("Bar");`

Comment: @Blachshma : ooohh i got it ...i see the concept.thank for describing..!!have good day..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] Url = {"ram", "syam"};
var persons = (from p in db.person
              where Url.Contain(p.name)
              select p).ToList();
```